# Menu toggle to screen resolution

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I was wondering is there a way to set the mobile menu toggle till the screen resolution(1310*400) for browser, My mobile toggle is set till till screen resolution 768px

```html
@media screen and (max-width: 768px)
{
#menuMobileToggle {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: so you want to add condition for width + hight?

Comment: `@media screen and (max-width: 1310px) and (max-height:400px)`

Comment: yes sir,so it shows full menu only on desktop,Mobile toggle on every other resolution